# Are questions on reconstructions of ancient proto-languages unwelcome?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently I have been heavily downvoted on all questions I asked mainly regarding reconstructions of ancient proto-languages.

Is this kind of questions unwelcome here? I mean, I am afraid of being auto-banned.

Answer (score 1):

"Proto-world" is almost pseudo-science. Personally I'd be happy to have zero questions about it. But it's not off-topic, and you're free to post questions about it.

However, there's a difference between asking about the research others have done on proposals for proto-world, and trying to establish proto-world yourself. This site isn't the right place for that kind of work. If you'd actually managed to find a convincing set of correspondences you'd want to publish that in a journal.

We probably should consider classifying questions of the type "is this proposed correspondence between unrelated language valid?" off-topic. That's arguably primary research, and belongs in journals, whereas this site is a secondary source. Just like primary research doesn't belong on Wikipedia, neither does it belong on Stack Exchange.

And whether you're asking about others' proto-* models or your own, expect downvotes when the evidence doesn't demand more than the null hypothesis (coincidence).

Comment: People should have a place to ask questions related to their research, no?

Comment: @Anixx Not in the peer review sense. Stack Exchange sites aren't for peer reviewing research. That's for journals.

Comment: Where are you getting the idea from that SE is not for “original research”? These sites can definitively be used by people with an original problem, as long as it’s not too large. I don’t see how a question about a proposed reconstruction and whether the reasoning behind it is valid would ever be “off topic”—if that is off topic, what on earth would be on topic? If there is a place to discuss work of others, there is also place to apply it in other contexts; you cannot separate the two.

Comment: I think the OP said proto-language, not proto-world.

Comment: @Lambie They've asked many questions. They tagged this one proto-world: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/48206/could-the-initial-d-in-the-word-for-tongue-be-originally-a-prefix

Comment: Well, all I saw was the insults thing, but no other questions like this. Anyway, it doesn't really matter. Thanks for explaining.